# Will it look good in my CV if I code up the same app or software using different paradigms?

Tags: resume

For example, I make an android app using different paradigms - functionally and imperatively. My premise is that it will look good on my resume, since I demonstrate that I can operate and implement software using various approaches.

Comment: Are you planning to do this as a project (for adding to your CV), or did you already do this, and are asking about how to advertise it on your CV?

Comment: plan to do it!!

Answer (score 6):

You could start a blog series doing just that, ie. translating imperative code to functional and vice-versa. There you can demonstrate your knowledge (to the potential employer) by talking about the code, esp. the bits that don't translate, what needs to be done differently etc.

The point here is not writing the code per se, but demonstrating you know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be fine, as long as these apps are well enough done and you have enough thought put into the resulting questions that might arise in an interview.

For example, if I was interviewing you and saw these apps, I'd be asking you which approach was "best", how you'd decide to use one tech over the other in future, etc. I'd be wanting to make sure you're not a 'shiny golden hammer' kind of person who finds out something new and then is determined to use it, even if it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As previous experience has shown, it is never a bad thing to have something to show when you go on an interview. I've had several job interviews where they asked if I had examples of my work. Sadly, all of my coding is done for employment, and they rarely allow me to parade around internal software (I do a lot of internal client work), so I've had no examples. One recruiter very seriously told me to "get a hobby" and make some non-work related sites or software in order to have something to present to a prospective employer.

As long as they work and look somewhat decent, and as long as you tell the interviewer that they are proof of concepts or prototypes, then by all means show them off. They all like to know they're not hiring a person with no idea what they're doing, or only know what academia has told them. (Academia and Reality very generally do not co-exist well. Hah)